# ora-01086 : save point was not established or invalid

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, savepoints

Ora-01086 : save point was not established or invalid.
KRD_UPD_BORCTAHSILATYAP_SP this SP throws errors .
When I test this loop below, I get the error: ora-01086

Normally it works without calling an external sp, I test it with an inline error and I rolledback to the save point. What am I missing ?

```
FOR rec IN (...records.....
               )
   LOOP
      SAVEPOINT odemeIslemiBaslangic;
      BEGIN


         CASE rec.prosedur_ad
            WHEN 'KRD' THEN

               KRD_UPD_BORCTAHSILATYAP_SP(rec.musterino, rec.urundegeri, rec.taksitno, v_MuhasebeReferans, v_IslemReferans, v_Tarih);
               IF v_MuhasebeReferans IS NOT NULL THEN
                  v_SonucKd  := 10;
                  v_Aciklama := 'Başarılı işlem';
               ELSE
                  v_SonucKd  := 9;
                  v_Aciklama := 'Borç bulunamadı';
               END IF;

         END CASE;
         cll_ins_tahsilatislem_sp(p_odemeno        => rec.odemeno,
                                  p_islemtarihi    => v_Tarih,
                                  p_musterino      => rec.musterino,
                                  p_urundeger      => rec.urundegeri,
                                  p_islemref       => v_IslemReferans,
                                  p_muhasebesubekd => rec.sube_kd,
                                  p_muhaseberef    => v_MuhasebeReferans,
                                  p_aciklama       => v_Aciklama,
                                  p_sonuc          => v_SonucKd,
                                  p_kayityapan     => v_KayitYapan,
                                  p_kayittrxkod    => v_KayitTrxKod);
         UPDATE cll_gecikmisbankaalacak u
            SET u.sonuc_kd = v_SonucKd
          WHERE u.odemeno = rec.odemeno
            AND u.kayit_drm = 'A';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT odemeIslemiBaslangic;
            v_SonucKd  := 1;
            v_Aciklama := 'İşlem Hata: ' || substr(SQLERRM, 1, 400);
            cll_ins_tahsilatislem_sp(p_odemeno        => rec.odemeno,
                                     p_islemtarihi    => v_Tarih,
                                     p_musterino      => rec.musterino,
                                     p_urundeger      => rec.urundegeri,
                                     p_islemref       => v_IslemReferans,
                                     p_muhasebesubekd => rec.sube_kd,
                                     p_muhaseberef    => v_MuhasebeReferans,
                                     p_aciklama       => v_Aciklama,
                                     p_sonuc          => v_SonucKd,
                                     p_kayityapan     => v_KayitYapan,
                                     p_kayittrxkod    => v_KayitTrxKod);
            UPDATE cll_gecikmisbankaalacak u
               SET u.sonuc_kd = v_SonucKd
             WHERE u.odemeno = rec.odemeno
               AND u.kayit_drm = 'A';
      END;

   END LOOP;
```

Comment: i'm not sure ,but i think that it is better that use your SAVEPOINT out of the loop

Comment: Is `KRD_UPD_BORCTAHSILATYAP_SP` rolling back on error; and if so, where too?

Comment: Yes it rolls back itself. or commits. @AlexPoole

Comment: It rolls back the whole transaction, not to its own savepoint? Then the savepoint you establish in the calling procedure will have been wiped out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your comment suggests that the procedure you are calling, `KRD_UPD_BORCTAHSILATYAP_SP`,  is rolling back the whole transaction, i.e. issuing a simple `ROLLBACK`.

From the [documentation for `ROLLBACK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9021.htm):

> Using `ROLLBACK` without the `TO SAVEPOINT` clause performs the following operations:
>
> - Ends the transaction
> - Undoes all changes in the current transaction
> - Erases all savepoints in the transaction
> - Releases any transaction locks

The savepoint you established in your calling block is therefore being erased, so you can no longer roll back to that.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when your inner code has commit a change, then you are trying to rollback to savepoint , which is technically not possible

Comment: Not an anwser, should be a comment.